# Get Project form "Project" CommandBar button

Tags: c#, .net, add-in, visual-studio-addins

I'm developing an addin for VS 2012. I added a button and command to the `Project` command bar.

Now I have button in right-click menu after clicking on `Project`.

All I want to do for now is list all `*.cs` files from the project on which that button was clicked and have access to edit them.

I need that info in "Exec" function that is "catching" my command.

How to do it?

Pieces of my code:

```
_CommandBars cmdBars = (_CommandBars)_applicationObject.CommandBars;

CommandBar vsBarProject = cmdBars["Project"];

CommandBarPopup pluginProjectFolderPopup = (CommandBarPopup)vsBarProject.Controls.Add(MsoControlType.msoControlPopup, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, 1, true);

pluginProjectFolderPopup.Caption = "Plugin";

try
{
    Command command = commands.AddNamedCommand2(_addInInstance, "TestRightClickProject", "Plugin test", "Testing right click command on code window", true, 59, ref contextGUIDS, (int)vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusSupported + (int)vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusEnabled, (int)vsCommandStyle.vsCommandStyleText, vsCommandControlType.vsCommandControlTypeButton);
    if ((commands != null) && (pluginProjectFolderPopup != null))
    {
        command.AddControl(pluginProjectFolderPopup.CommandBar, 1);
    }
}
catch (System.ArgumentException)
{
}
```

UPDATE:
I have no choise. I have to use addins

Comment: (Tangential warning: The next version of Visual Studio (currently known as Visual Studio "14") doesn't support add-ins.  You might want to consider writing an extension instead.)

Comment: @RichieHindle I have no choise. I have to use addins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the answer to this question:

[Visual Studio 2010 Plug-in - Adding a context-menu to the Solution Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017063/visual-studio-2010-plug-in-adding-a-context-menu-to-the-solution-explorer)

Once you determine the project being selected (see

```
_applicationObject.SelectedItems.Item(1).Project
```

)

You can use ProjectKinds.vsProjectKindSolutionFolder to get the project folder (see 
[How to get folders under projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14272729/how-to-get-folders-under-projects) )

Then iterate through the desired folder and subfolders.